# How to check if textfield.text is in the format of NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextfield, string-formatting, textfield

I've tried

```
[textField.text  isEqual:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
```

but it tells me it is implicit and does not work in ARC.

Answer (score 0):

That's not at all what needs to be done. You need to actually create an `NSNumberFormatter`, sets its style to `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`, and then use it to parse the text of the text field.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formater setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSNumber *result = [formatter numberFromString:textField.text];
if (result) {
    // The text had a valid currency value
} else {
    // The text was not a valid current value
}
```